# dual boot windows linux

Tags: linux, windows10, grub

tengo un problema con mi dual boot entre windows y linux, tengo dos discos duros, en el que disco1 tiene instalado windows10 y en el disco2 tengo linux.
el problema viene cuando quiero iniciar uno de los dos, ya que tengo que dejar de predeterminado un disco que sera el que se ejecute siempre, y si quiero cambiar de SO, tengo que entrar en la bios para arrancar desde el otro disco.
he intentado cambiar e introducir una entrada windows al grub de linux, pero al tenerlo en un disco distinto no me detecta el SO. ¿como podria añadirlo?
gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Creo que esto es lo que buscas: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506793/21764, no tengo tiempo ahora de escribir una respuesta, pero si te sirve, dejame saber y lo haré más adelante. Un saludo.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero no lo he conseguido. Si ejecuto el os-prober no me detecta el arranque de windows, pero si lo hago con fdisk si que lo detecta.He intentado hacer lo que pone en el link, pero nada... un saludo.

Comment: No era una respuesta, sino un comentario. Lamento que no te haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Hay que dejar el boot en uno de los discos, que será el que ejecute grub o lo que elijas.